# rails config.assets.precompile for specific sub folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Ive some very heavy external stylesheets in app/assets/stylesheets/external/calendars
I dont want to include the stylesheets into the application.css as they are used infrequently

Yet i want them precompiled.

Ho w do i use config.assets.precompile o selectively precompile all stylesheets nside this folder ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is covered in section 4.1 of the [Asset Pipeline Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

```
config.assets.precompile += ["*external/calendars*"]
```

Answer (score 16):

You can simple write it like this:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['directory1/*', 'directory2/*', 'file.js']
```

Or use a cleaner syntax like this:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( directory1/* directory2/* file.js )
```