# config.assets.precompile - include a folder of files? or kill the precompile 'feature' entirely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have read and tried the Assets Pipeline guide here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

... which shows how to include specific files in a manually created and updated list, --OR-- the Proc which includes a directory (or directories) but then excludes all the other files which Rails ordinarily includes.

I want to += my folder of files to the normally included files.

I have tried the answers:

[Rails config.assets.precompile setting to process all CSS and JS files in app/assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097993/rails-config-assets-precompile-setting-to-process-all-css-and-js-files-in-app-as)

[What is the purpose of config.assets.precompile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012434/what-is-the-purpose-of-config-assets-precompile)

[rails config.assets.precompile for specific sub folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001274/rails-config-assets-precompile-for-specific-sub-folder)

... the last of which appears to show a solution:

```
config.assets.precompile += ["*external/calendars*"]
```

which I changed to:

```
    config.assets.precompile += %w["*javascript*"]
```

or 
        config.assets.precompile += ["*javascript*"]
(and about 20 other variations.)

... to get my assets/javascript folder.  But the directory is not included, as evidenced by the error "...isn't precompiled."

The third method, is to give it

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
```

... which works, but leads to a very, very long compile, I would assume finding every JS file it can discover, anywhere.

Needless to say, adding files to a manually updated list is not suitable for an in-progress application - and losing whatever unknown things Rails precompiles with an exclusionary Proc won't cut it either (yet those are the only two examples in the docs).

Is there not a simple wildcard solution to "+-=" a folder - or perhaps to just turn this 'feature' off, specify my JS per view, and still have it work on Heroku?

----EDIT - It gets more irrational the deeper I look.
Essentially, the solution is, "Load all the things Rails finds A-OK in Development Mode." And yet such an option does not exist?

The production.rb file, referring to the precompile line, says:

```
  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
```

... and application.js has:

```
//= require_tree .
```

... so that should load all the files under that directory - but it doesn't.  Why?  The deeper I dig, the less sense this makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice when dealing with multiple CSS/JS files to add to the asset pipeline is to simply create a new manifest for those files:

Let's say you have some JS files under `lib/assets/javascripts/external/calendars` and you want to load them through the asset pipeline.

You want to create an `index.js` manifest file with the following content:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require_tree .
```

This way all JS files you add into the `external/calendars` directory will be included by default thanks to the `require_tree .` directive.

Now, in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file add the following line:

```
//= require calendars
```

This should find your "calendars' manifest index file" and load all dependent JS files. No need to add anything into the asset pipeline, it will just work.

Comment: I am only trying to include the files in app/assets/javascripts/ - no subdirectories at this point.  I added the 'index.js' file into 'app/assets/javascripts/' folder (was that the correct location?), and put '//= require javascripts' into the 'app/assets/javascripts/application.js' file.  I also commented out the 'config.assets.precompile' line in the 'production.rb' file.

Now when I run 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' I get the error "couldn't find file 'javascripts'".

Comment: OK, I see that one MUST use a subdirectory to get this method to work.  I created one, put my files there, and precompile created the /public/assets/blah files.  Note that one's JS files are included within the minified application.js file there - not in their own js files, as they were using some other methods.   Unfortunately, when I pushed to Heroku, the files are still not working - 'blah.js isn't precompiled' error - to spite no errors when the slug precompiled in x seconds.

Comment: Added back the config.assets.precompile line in production.rb as+= %w( index.js )

Comment: Same error ... Ahh, because the file is referenced in the view, and now it doesn't exist as its own file anymore, but is mixed into application.js - sigh.  Time to rework all my views to take out any references to my independent js files.  Did that for a couple to test and they work now.  Thanks for a pointer in the right direction Pierre.

Comment: You welcome :) Glad it helped you. Working with the asset pipeline is not that easy :(